# forEach returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I'm using moment.js and trying to process a date using that code

```
function toISOdate (date) {
    return moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toISOString()
}
function toMomentDate (date) {
    return moment(date)
}


let input = "25.11.2017-25.11.2017"
let dateArray = input
                    .split('-')
                    .forEach(toISOdate)
console.log(dateArray, input)
```

But the problem is that dateArray returns undefined. Maybe it's very obvious mistake, but I can't find it.

Comment: I downvoted because the answer to the question is found within the documentation's first paragraph.

Comment: If `forEach` returns `undefined`, then everything works exactly as it should.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [simply read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that returns:

> A new array with each element being the result of the callback function.

instead of [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return). [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return) doesn't return anything (`undefined`).